# How to disable svn-needs-lock by default?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-lock

After I got a fresh workstation computer, there is something different with my SVN setup.
All files I create have `svn:needs-lock` property set by default. Actually this wasn't the case in the past and I do not really need it because there too little concurrent developers here.

Could you please tell me how to configure my computer to not set this property by default?

System: Windows 7

SVN client: TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be various reasons why you have `svn:needs-lock` property automatically applied on your versioned files:

1. You have [`enable-auto-props = yes`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html) set in `[miscellany]` section of you `%APPDATA%\Subversion\config` file (Subversion runtime configuration area) and the `[auto-props]` section is configured to set `svn:needs-lock` on every file.
2. You have [`tsvn:autoprops`](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-auto-props) property applied on folders in your repository.
3. You use Subversion 1.8 client and the repository has [`svn:auto-props`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto) property applied on it's root or project's root.

Have I missed something?